# How should I best prepare for abstract algebra?

Tags: abstract-algebra

I've taken calculus through multivariable and a calculus-based statistics class. However, I struggled with some of the proof stuff in Calc II, and I'm seeing now that that's probably going to burn me unless I get it fixed before classes start again in January. I'm pretty nervous for it.

Are there things I should review in preparation? How do you even get better at proofs? My class will be using *A Book of Abstract Algebra, Second Edition* by Pinter.

Comment: I know it may sound a bit strange, but algebraic proofs are a different animal then the kind of proofs you'd encounter in calculus.  Of course, you'll still have to muddle through the learning process of what constitutes "rigor" (not an easy process), but I wouldn't worry all that much.  Often the first time that one writes a truly rigorous proof is after entering graduate school.  Not the way we'd like it to be, but just an unfortunate reality.

Comment: That is strange! Is there any way to explain how they're different? I know it might not make sense to me because I haven't taken algebra yet.

Comment: You go through the algebra you already know and dissect it, while abstracting the concepts involved. The first time I read an abstract algebra book changed the way I looked at math (for the better). Have fun! The proofs don't require as much insight, at least not at the beginning, but they really make you think about things in terms of definition. What you will prove will seem obvious, but won't necessarily be trivial to show.

Comment: @Alex, I have found that each person seems to have a preference between algebra and analysis.  Some are good at both, but most are a lot better at one than the other.  One major difference is that abstract algebra (at the introductory level) is discrete, whereas calculus is founded on notions of continuity.  There is nothing (for the most part) in abstract algebra that deals with limits, much less continuity and differentiability.  Of course way down the road, algebra can become quite topological and analytic (compact Lie groups, for example).  This is _not_ what you'll be studying.

Comment: If you're going to be learning stuff like group theory then it might help to go over some basic set theory (like how to prove that two sets are equal to each other: if A=B you need to show $A\subset B$ *and* $B\subset A$, because I know a lot of math courses will do those proofs without explicitly telling students how they work). Most of the proofs you'll have to do though will just be based on checking that a specific definition is satisfied.

Comment: I disagree with Doc about the notion that the proofs are different sorts of animals. I also disagree with him about the "rigorous proof" bit. Yet it is true that the topics are *very* different. I got burned trying to do abstract algebra from the wrong sort of direction, and am only now starting to approach it again, having been motivated by studying some topology of all things.

Answer (score 2):

In order to prepare for a course in abstract algebra follow these steps,

$(1)$ Familiarize yourself with $\mathbb{R,Z,Q,C}$.

```
  -Understand how arithmetic operations such as work in generality.
```

$(2)$ Get used to modular arithmetic now if you haven't done so already.

```
  -this will help you understand how congruences in different mods work.
```

$(3)$ Definitions are you friend.

```
  -As it has been stated before, "you will not just stumble onto a proof in 

   abstract algebra.
```

$(4)$ Review basic number theory concepts such as gcd, lcm, divisors, prime factorization.

```
  -This will help when dealing with the euclidean algorithm and much more.
```

$(5)$ Be comfortable with the binomial theorem.

```
  -This will help when you need to derive multiple angle formulas.
```

Lastly, just get an old syllabus and really try to understand the definitions. Play with them and do a lot of examples.

$\textbf{Assuming your first course will be covering field theory, and ring theory.}$